# how to convert type 'system.linq.iqueryable<byte[]>' to 'byte[]'

Tags: linq-to-sql, arrays, iqueryable, type-conversion

In Linq to SQL asp.net, I want to fetch a specific image from database and display on an aspx page. I declared returned type as "var" on the code. So after fetching the image, it assigns image to var type.

Here is the code:

```
var db = from c in context.Images
                         where c.imageId == iID
                         select c.imageData;
return new MemoryStream((byte[])db);  ---->> this line of code gives error
```

It gives this compile error: Cannot convert type 'system.linq.iqueryable' to 'byte[]'.

How can I convert 'system.linq.iqueryable type to byte[] ?

Comment: you should use the SingleOrDefault selector for linq, so you can get only a single object and not an IQueryable. Also in SingleOrDefault<> you can specify the type so you can avoid casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're selecting a collection of `byte[]` rather than a single `byte[]`.

Depending on the behavior you want for your application, you can use `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, or `FirstOrDeault`:

```
var image = context.Images.FirstOrDefault(i => i.imageId == ID);
if(image == null)
{
    // Handle the case where no image was found.
    //
    // First or Single would throw Exceptions in this case
    // if that's what you want.
}
else
{
    return new MemoryStream(image.imageData);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Justin, could you please help me about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699751/how-to-return-the-query-result-as-a-specific-object-type-in-linq

Answer (score 1):

try below line this work for me

`var db = (context.Images.FirstOrDefault(i => i.imageId == ID).ImageData`