# how to return the query result as a specific object type in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, return-type

Sorry I'm new to LINQ and Entity framework.

When a linq query fetches a whole Entity, 
how can i return the result as an object type? 
I mean not just a field but also to return all the fields of that specific record, as one entity.

For example a Staff table in sql. To return a staff object entity.

if i write Linq code like this:

```
var db= (from c in context.Staff
                          where c.id == sId
                          select new { s.sId,s.staffNo,s.name,s.surname,s.image});
return db; ---> here
```

Gives an error because i want to return result as Staff object.

How can it return as a table column object?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As per your comments, you need a single object returned from your method.*

To return a single Item you have following options.

1. [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx): Returns first item from the collection, if there are no matching items then an exception would be thrown.
2. [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx): Works same like `First` except it would return `null` if there are no matching records.
3. [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx): Returns only one item from the list, It will throw exception if the collection contains more than one item or the collection is empty. A possible usage is when querying against primary key. Only one record should be returned. Exceptional case should be when there are more than one record.
4. [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx): Works on the same principal as `Single` except it would return null if the collection is empty.

All these methods can be added at the end of your query syntax or could receive a predicate. Like:

```
var db=  (from c in context.Staff
         where c.id == sId
         select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
var db = context.Staff.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.id == sId);
```

If your field `id` is a primary key then use `SingleOrDefault`.

---

*(Old Answer*

If you are trying to return particular columns from a table, then **you can't project your result to your class `Staff` since that is generated through the framework.**

You have two options. First create another class with properties same as your result set and return its object.

Or instead of selecting specific columns, select all columns and then return `Staff` type object.

```
var db=  from c in context.Staff
         where c.id == sId
         select c;
return db;
```

If you want to create an other class lets say `PartialStaff` then you can do:

```
var db=  from c in context.Staff
         where c.id == sId
         select new  PartialStaff
             { 
               Id = s.sId,
               //.......rest of the properties
             };
```

But then your method return type should be `PartialStaff` type collection.

Comment: I want to return just 1 Staff column, sId is primary key here in sql table. So the record will be 1. And Entity Framework creates all objects itself already isn't it? I knew like that

Comment: @perlynsparks, that is one staff record, not one column. In that case you can use First/FirstOrDefault, Single/SingleOrDefault, depending on the requirement.

Comment: Sorry yes, surely it is a record. The return type is what matters here for me. Because i put this query inside a method; which returns a Staff object type..

Comment: @perlynsparks, I have modified my answer, I hope it is bit clear now

Comment: Based on what you said i ve changed the code like this:public Staff ShowByID(int id)
{
 Staff stf=new Staff();
 var x=(from s in cont.Staff
                         where s.id == id
                         select new { s.id, s.name,... }).SingleOrDefault();
 if(x!=null)
 {
  stf.id=x.id;
  stf.name=x.name;
  //...
 }
 else
 {
  //...
 }
 return stf;
}

Comment: @perlynsparks, why you have to do :  `new { s.id, s.name,... }` why not just `select s` ????

Comment: Dont know if there is more convenient way other than this code.. Thank you for all of the informations, it helped me a lot:)

Comment: Cuz i select some of the columns in the record

Answer (score 2):

> When a linq query fetches a whole Entity, how can i return the result
>   as an object type? I mean not just a field but also to return all the
>   fields of that specific column, as one entity.
>
> For example a Staff table in sql. To return a staff object entity.

You could try this one:

```
var db= (from c in context.Staff
         where c.id == sId
         select c);
```

or

```
db = context.Staff.Where(s=>s.id == sId);
```

The result of the above query is a *sequence* of Staff objects, `IEnumerable<Staff>`. Specifically, this sequence will contain all the `Staff` objects in `context.Staff`, whose `id` is equal to `sId`.

> Gives an error because i want to return result as Staff object.

Now If you are sure that there would be at most one item in `context.Staff` with the given `id`, you could try this:

```
 var db = (from c in context.Staff
         where c.id == sId
         select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

or

```
var db = context.Staff.SingleOrDefault(s=>s.id == sId);
```

This query will return the single `Staff` object with the given `id` and if there isn't any `Staff` object in `context.Staff` with this id, will return `null`.

Comment: The "sId" is primary key in the sql table. It is unique so the result will be one specific Staff object here..

Comment: @perlynsparks ah allrighty then. Then that you need is the second query I have posted. Please give it a go and let me know. Thanks